# how to use two aws ec2 instances(1 gpu and 1 cpu instance) with one storage to(run code, store/share files) & reduce cost

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-efs, deep-learning-ami

My team is using a gpu instance to run machine learning tensorflow based, yolo,computer vision applications and use it for training machine learning models also.. It costs 7$ an hour and has 8 gpu's. Was trying to reduce costs on it. We need 8 gpu's for faster training and sometimes many people can use different gpu's at the same time.

For our use case we are not using sometimes the gpu's(8 gpus) at all for atleast 1-2 weeks of a month. But a use of the gpu may arrive during that time but maynot also. So i wanted to know is there a way to edit the code and do all cpu intensive operations when gpu not needed through a low cost cpu instance. And turn on the gpu instance only when needed use it and then stop it when work done.

I thought of using efs for putting code on the shared file system and then running from there but i read an article( https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2018/getting-best-performance-out-amazon-efs ) where its written that i should never run code from network based drives because the speed can become really slow. So i dont know if its good to run machine learning application from efs file system. I was thinking of making virtual environments on folders in efs but i dont think that is a good idea.

Could anyone  suggest good ways of achieving this and reduce costs. And if you are suggesting to use an instance with lower number of gpu's that i have considered but we sometimes need 8 gpu's for faster training but we dont use the gpus at all for 1-2 weeks but the costs are still incurred.

Please suggest a way on how to achieve a low cost for this use case without using spot or reserved instances.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few thoughts:

- GPU instances now allow hibernation, so when launching your GPU select the new Stop Instance behavior 'hibernate' which will let you turn it off for 2 weeks but spin it up quickly if necessary
- If you only have one instance, look into using EBS for data storage with a high volume of provisioned iops to move data on/off your instance quickly
- Alternately, move your model to Sagemaker to ensure you are only charged for GPU use when you are actively training your model
- If you are applying your model (inferencing) move that workload to a cheap instance. A trained yolo model can run inferencing on very small CPU instances, no need for a GPU for that part of the workload at all.

Comment: i think i am using an ebs volume only for data storage but its general perpose ssd). So l wanted to ask if i turn off my gpu instances for 2 weeks how do the people work on the code and access the data for that instance . Like i ll have to keep mounting,unmounting, remounting to different instances my ebs volume which is very tedious. I said 2 weeks means like as a collection of days when its not used in a month. So it works like sometimes for 2 consecutive days gpu is not used but then its used.Or sometimes we need it every alternate day then what should we do.

Comment: Hi, @matthewarthur would you by any chance know the answer to the above commment?

Comment: You would create a stand-alone EBS volume that you would mount to your GPU for training, etc, then dismount and mount to a cheap (T2/M4) instance when modifying code. Leave the root volume of the GPU instance alone and work from this separate EBS volume.

Comment: oh thanks @matthewarthur ......just one more question - can i mount , unmount the stand alone machines without turning them off right and with aws cli? And also can i mount the stand alone ebs volume to the t2 instance when the p2 (gpu instance) is in off state or do i need to unmount it from the gpu instance first with aws cli? And all this is possible right to do with aws cli?

Comment: @userrk Yes, this is all via the cli. Start with this documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-attaching-volume.html

Comment: hi, @matthewarthur but how will multiple people use this method. If someone is editing in t2 on the standalone ssd and one person wants to use the gpu . then one person has to stop ,save his work then start on another instance. So would i need to create multiple standalone ssd's for different users?

Comment: Yes, you are thinking correctly. So you could use Git for code deployment and just git pull from the GPU whenever needed, and you could use S3 for data storage.

Comment: ok thanks ... just one more thing @ matthewarthur i was trying to pip install requirements from a virtualenv to a virtualenv in the new volume i attached but it gives me errors like (--  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement anaconda-client==1.6.9 (from -r requirementsalpha.txt (line 5)) (from versions: 1.1.1, 1.2.2)
No matching distribution found for anaconda-client==1.6.9 )--) . My question - is this happening because i mounted my drive in a different location. I mounted in /newvolume but the virtualenv that i am copying requirements from is in /home/ubuntu/somefolder.

Comment: and @matthewarthur if i mount my drive in a position like /home/ubuntu/newfolder will i not face these issues. And also is it safe to mount in the /home/ubuntu/ folder or should i only mount /newvolume. And can i unmount from /newvolume and mount on /home/ubuntu/newfolder to instantly remove this error. And also wanted to know why which method is better.....But thanks for your responses

Comment: and i also get errors while unmounting like target is busy when i try to unmount with sudo umount -d /dev/xvdf and i dont know how to solve this issue.Do you know how to resolve this.
------
umount: /newvolume: target is busy
        (In some cases useful info about processes that
         use the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1).)
-------

Comment: Try stopping the instance before unmounting. You won't lose any ephemeral data but you can unmount.

Comment: i wanted to not be able to stop the instance to unmount so that i dont waste so much time everytime....stop t2 then attach to p2 .....then stop p2 then attach to t2 because the other team members would be  working on the t2 instance. But if i turn of the instance i will only need to detach right not unmount because it would not be connected to the instance after turn off. Do you know a way to stop any processes that use the volume so unmount is easy.....and also do you know if i can mount to /home/ubuntu/somefolder or i can only mount to /somefolder which i am currently doing? ...thanks

Comment: hi, @matthewarthur would you by any chance know the answers to the above question in my last comment

Comment: @userrk I don't know offhand, unfortunately. Sorry and good luck!

Comment: I found all the answers ... i can mount in /home/ubuntu directory. virtualenv problem was coming because i was mounting at /newvolume and not after /home/ubuntu so maybe some base packages problem.the device is busy was coming because i was accessing it via sftp which was not showing up with lsof /fuser and by closing my ssh browser mobaxterm and only doing ssh with it helped to umount(unmount the drive) ...thanks for all the help

Answer (score 2):

To reduce inference costs, you can use Elastic Inference which supports pay-per-use functionality:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-inference.html

Comment: i read about elastic inference....so is it as easy to run the inference on the gpu as mentioned lets say in any github repo of a project based on tensorflow(like follow instructions on ubuntu with  certain settings for elastic inference)...or would i need to follow certain steps to make it work with elastic inference(like use docker or sagemaker etc). And its only for inference right not for training right?

Comment: Correct: Elastic Inference is for Inference. Check this guide for sample usage: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dlami/latest/devguide/tutorial-tf-elastic-inference.html